# Undefined index: oauth_problem HWIOAuthBundle when using yahoo

Tags: symfony, oauth, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle, yahoo-oauth

I have Integrated FOSUserBundle and HWIOAuthBundle as explained in http://m2mdas.github.io/blog/2013/11/21/integrate-hwioauthbundle-with-fosuserbundle/

It works fine with twitter, facebook, linkedIn. but using yahoo after creating new project app and configure it as explained on my project when use yahoo it shows me

ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: oauth_problem in C:\xxxx\vendor\hwi\oauth-bundle\HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner\GenericOAuth1ResourceOwner.php line 163

so, please can anyone help me resolving that issue ?!